# How to access HttpServletResponse staticly in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to write some message to response if exceptions occur in controller ,To do this I need response object .Can I access current response/request object staticly or I have to pass this object to exception too.like in jsf  **(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse());**

```
 List<View_Probes> getAllProbes(HttpServletResponse response)  throws ResourceNotFoundException{
        try {
          List<Probe>  probes=   inseptraPersistenceService.listAllProbes();

          List<View_Probes> result=  mapper.mapAll(probes, View_Probes.class);

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
             throw  new ResourceNotFoundException(e);

        }
    }


@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {


    public ResourceNotFoundException() {

    }

    public ResourceNotFoundException(Throwable e) {
        super(e);
    }


}
```

Comment: I think it must be possible .